# (css) How to put text on top of each image in image slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having some setbacks when trying to put text on top of the image slider. I want my text to show when I hover on the active image. When I have one image, I will set the text `position: absolute` and it's done. However, I have produced my images inside a map function, while using the `transform: translate(___px, ____px)` to moving around when user trigger the sliding. `position: absolute` will not work in this case, as all texts will be stack on top of each other, and I have to manually separate them with those dynamic `transform: translate(___px, ____px)`. Plus I have an event listener to adjust the `transform: translate(___px, ____px)` when I resize the window.

I not able to think of any valid solution for this, I have tried putting the texts outside the map function, but the text will detached from the image  when sliding or window resizing. I can't really think of any valid solution for this.

I have reproduced my image slider in the below link. You can check it out if you are interested in. Much appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leaf-riwf0p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can't see the image slider in the codesandbox demo.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save, I have updated it.

Comment: Could you provide some reproducible code. So that it will be easier for people to assist you with your problem @Hoe.

Comment: Please visit https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-leaf-riwf0p?file=/src/App.js, it should work now.